# How to get the complete list of autosys jobs with there dependency

Tags: autosys

Can you Please help mw with getting the complete list of jobs present on Autosys server or Box with there details ?

IS there any utility available ?

Answer (score 3):

autorep -J ALL | cat > jobList.txt

Answer (score 3):

autorep -J %BOX_NAME% -q will spit out all jobs in a box.

Note that the % sign denotes a wild card